# How to plot values for multiple factors from one column across several dates in pandas + matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've got a data frame that looks like this:

```
df=pd.Dataframe({'animal': {Timestamp('2014-11-12 00:00:00'): 'dog',
  Timestamp('2014-11-13 00:00:00'): 'rabbit',
  Timestamp('2014-11-14 00:00:00'): 'rabbit',
  Timestamp('2014-11-15 00:00:00'): 'rabbit',
  Timestamp('2014-11-16 00:00:00'): 'rabbit',
  Timestamp('2014-11-17 00:00:00'): 'rabbit',
  Timestamp('2014-11-18 00:00:00'): 'dog',
  Timestamp('2014-11-19 00:00:00'): 'rabbit',
  Timestamp('2014-11-20 00:00:00'): 'dog',
  Timestamp('2014-11-21 00:00:00'): 'dog',
  Timestamp('2014-12-01 00:00:00'): 'rabbit',
  Timestamp('2014-12-02 00:00:00'): 'dog',
  Timestamp('2014-12-03 00:00:00'): 'dog',
  Timestamp('2014-12-04 00:00:00'): 'rabbit',
  Timestamp('2014-12-05 00:00:00'): 'rabbit',
  Timestamp('2014-12-06 00:00:00'): 'dog',
  Timestamp('2014-12-07 00:00:00'): 'dog',
  Timestamp('2014-12-08 00:00:00'): 'rabbit',
  Timestamp('2014-12-09 00:00:00'): 'rabbit',
  Timestamp('2014-12-10 00:00:00'): 'rabbit',
  Timestamp('2014-12-11 00:00:00'): 'rabbit',
  Timestamp('2014-12-12 00:00:00'): 'rabbit',
  Timestamp('2014-12-13 00:00:00'): 'rabbit',
  Timestamp('2014-12-14 00:00:00'): 'rabbit',
  Timestamp('2014-12-15 00:00:00'): 'dog',
  Timestamp('2014-12-16 00:00:00'): 'dog',
  Timestamp('2014-12-17 00:00:00'): 'dog',
  Timestamp('2014-12-18 00:00:00'): 'rabbit',
  Timestamp('2014-12-19 00:00:00'): 'rabbit',
  Timestamp('2014-12-20 00:00:00'): 'dog'},
 'count': {Timestamp('2014-11-12 00:00:00'): 6136,
  Timestamp('2014-11-13 00:00:00'): 14620,
  Timestamp('2014-11-14 00:00:00'): 16437,
  Timestamp('2014-11-15 00:00:00'): 17273,
  Timestamp('2014-11-16 00:00:00'): 15302,
  Timestamp('2014-11-17 00:00:00'): 15180,
  Timestamp('2014-11-18 00:00:00'): 7177,
  Timestamp('2014-11-19 00:00:00'): 16193,
  Timestamp('2014-11-20 00:00:00'): 8226,
  Timestamp('2014-11-21 00:00:00'): 9741,
  Timestamp('2014-12-01 00:00:00'): 26237,
  Timestamp('2014-12-02 00:00:00'): 12146,
  Timestamp('2014-12-03 00:00:00'): 12910,
  Timestamp('2014-12-04 00:00:00'): 25820,
  Timestamp('2014-12-05 00:00:00'): 29323,
  Timestamp('2014-12-06 00:00:00'): 17294,
  Timestamp('2014-12-07 00:00:00'): 15219,
  Timestamp('2014-12-08 00:00:00'): 26174,
  Timestamp('2014-12-09 00:00:00'): 27112,
  Timestamp('2014-12-10 00:00:00'): 27131,
  Timestamp('2014-12-11 00:00:00'): 28268,
  Timestamp('2014-12-12 00:00:00'): 34059,
  Timestamp('2014-12-13 00:00:00'): 39162,
  Timestamp('2014-12-14 00:00:00'): 38314,
  Timestamp('2014-12-15 00:00:00'): 19807,
  Timestamp('2014-12-16 00:00:00'): 20606,
  Timestamp('2014-12-17 00:00:00'): 21552,
  Timestamp('2014-12-18 00:00:00'): 36499,
  Timestamp('2014-12-19 00:00:00'): 42163,
  Timestamp('2014-12-20 00:00:00'): 30301},
 'day': {Timestamp('2014-11-12 00:00:00'): 12,
  Timestamp('2014-11-13 00:00:00'): 13,
  Timestamp('2014-11-14 00:00:00'): 14,
  Timestamp('2014-11-15 00:00:00'): 15,
  Timestamp('2014-11-16 00:00:00'): 16,
  Timestamp('2014-11-17 00:00:00'): 17,
  Timestamp('2014-11-18 00:00:00'): 18,
  Timestamp('2014-11-19 00:00:00'): 19,
  Timestamp('2014-11-20 00:00:00'): 20,
  Timestamp('2014-11-21 00:00:00'): 21,
  Timestamp('2014-12-01 00:00:00'): 1,
  Timestamp('2014-12-02 00:00:00'): 2,
  Timestamp('2014-12-03 00:00:00'): 3,
  Timestamp('2014-12-04 00:00:00'): 4,
  Timestamp('2014-12-05 00:00:00'): 5,
  Timestamp('2014-12-06 00:00:00'): 6,
  Timestamp('2014-12-07 00:00:00'): 7,
  Timestamp('2014-12-08 00:00:00'): 8,
  Timestamp('2014-12-09 00:00:00'): 9,
  Timestamp('2014-12-10 00:00:00'): 10,
  Timestamp('2014-12-11 00:00:00'): 11,
  Timestamp('2014-12-12 00:00:00'): 12,
  Timestamp('2014-12-13 00:00:00'): 13,
  Timestamp('2014-12-14 00:00:00'): 14,
  Timestamp('2014-12-15 00:00:00'): 15,
  Timestamp('2014-12-16 00:00:00'): 16,
  Timestamp('2014-12-17 00:00:00'): 17,
  Timestamp('2014-12-18 00:00:00'): 18,
  Timestamp('2014-12-19 00:00:00'): 19,
  Timestamp('2014-12-20 00:00:00'): 20},
 'month': {Timestamp('2014-11-12 00:00:00'): 11,
  Timestamp('2014-11-13 00:00:00'): 11,
  Timestamp('2014-11-14 00:00:00'): 11,
  Timestamp('2014-11-15 00:00:00'): 11,
  Timestamp('2014-11-16 00:00:00'): 11,
  Timestamp('2014-11-17 00:00:00'): 11,
  Timestamp('2014-11-18 00:00:00'): 11,
  Timestamp('2014-11-19 00:00:00'): 11,
  Timestamp('2014-11-20 00:00:00'): 11,
  Timestamp('2014-11-21 00:00:00'): 11,
  Timestamp('2014-12-01 00:00:00'): 12,
  Timestamp('2014-12-02 00:00:00'): 12,
  Timestamp('2014-12-03 00:00:00'): 12,
  Timestamp('2014-12-04 00:00:00'): 12,
  Timestamp('2014-12-05 00:00:00'): 12,
  Timestamp('2014-12-06 00:00:00'): 12,
  Timestamp('2014-12-07 00:00:00'): 12,
  Timestamp('2014-12-08 00:00:00'): 12,
  Timestamp('2014-12-09 00:00:00'): 12,
  Timestamp('2014-12-10 00:00:00'): 12,
  Timestamp('2014-12-11 00:00:00'): 12,
  Timestamp('2014-12-12 00:00:00'): 12,
  Timestamp('2014-12-13 00:00:00'): 12,
  Timestamp('2014-12-14 00:00:00'): 12,
  Timestamp('2014-12-15 00:00:00'): 12,
  Timestamp('2014-12-16 00:00:00'): 12,
  Timestamp('2014-12-17 00:00:00'): 12,
  Timestamp('2014-12-18 00:00:00'): 12,
  Timestamp('2014-12-19 00:00:00'): 12,
  Timestamp('2014-12-20 00:00:00'): 12}}
```

I'm trying to plot a line graph for the counts of each of the two animals across a seven day period; essentially, I'm aiming for a time series for each animal to be displayed on the same graph.

Here's my code:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True, infer_datetime_format = True)
df['animal'] = df['animal'].astype('category')
df = df.set_index('date')

grouped = df.groupby('animal')
for key, group in grouped:
    data = group.groupby(lambda x: x.day)
    data['count'].plot(label=key)


plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Instead of something where counts for both animals are displayed, like this:
[image]

The closest I get to is the following:
[image]

I feel like I'm missing an obvious chunk here, but can't quite figure this out.

**EDIT**: I couldn't quite grasp how to order by both month and day, so appended some data to the data frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a `day` column to store all the day numbers:

```
df['day'] = df.index.day
```

and since we want the days ordered along the `x`-axis, sort the column too:

```
df = df.sort_values(by='day')
```

Then you can group by `animal` and plot each subgroup:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['animal'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for key, group in grouped:
    group.plot('day', 'count', label=key, ax=ax)
```

Note that `group.plot` calls `DataFrame.plot` which allows you to specify the columns to be used for the `x-` and `y-`axes. In contrast, `group['count'].plot`calls `Series.plot`, which assumes the `x-axis` is the index and the `y-axis` is the Series's values.

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp


df = pd.DataFrame({'animal': {12: 'dog', 44: 'dog', 47: 'dog', 69: 'rabbit', 76: 'rabbit', 84: 'dog', 122: 'rabbit', 162: 'rabbit', 177: 'rabbit', 190: 'rabbit', 217: 'dog', 219: 'dog', 220: 'dog', 226: 'rabbit'},
 'count': {12: 34573, 44: 30676, 47: 41821, 69: 56880, 76: 73172, 84: 30581, 122: 52895, 162: 58430, 177: 57132, 190: 53903, 217: 32001, 219: 35776, 220: 31095, 226: 53809},
 'date': {12: Timestamp('2014-12-29 00:00:00'), 44: Timestamp('2014-12-28 00:00:00'), 47: Timestamp('2014-12-31 00:00:00'), 69: Timestamp('2014-12-29 00:00:00'), 76: Timestamp('2014-12-31 00:00:00'), 84: Timestamp('2014-12-26 00:00:00'), 122: Timestamp('2014-12-25 00:00:00'), 162: Timestamp('2014-12-30 00:00:00'), 177: Timestamp('2014-12-27 00:00:00'), 190: Timestamp('2014-12-28 00:00:00'), 217: Timestamp('2014-12-27 00:00:00'), 219: Timestamp('2014-12-30 00:00:00'), 220: Timestamp('2014-12-25 00:00:00'), 226: Timestamp('2014-12-26 00:00:00')}})

df['animal'] = df['animal'].astype('category')
df = df.set_index('date')


df['day'] = df.index.day
df = df.sort_values(by='day')
grouped = df.groupby(['animal'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for key, group in grouped:
    group.plot('day', 'count', label=key, ax=ax)

plt.legend(loc='best')

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

For the revised question, if you want the entire date along the `x-axis`, then perhaps it is easiest to just use the `Series.plot` (as you were doing in your original code):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

df = pd.DataFrame({'animal': ['dog', 'rabbit', 'rabbit', 'rabbit', 'rabbit', 'rabbit', 'dog', 'rabbit', 'dog', 'dog', 'rabbit', 'dog', 'dog', 'rabbit', 'rabbit', 'dog', 'dog', 'rabbit', 'rabbit', 'rabbit', 'rabbit', 'rabbit', 'rabbit', 'rabbit', 'dog', 'dog', 'dog', 'rabbit', 'rabbit', 'dog'], 'count': [6136, 14620, 16437, 17273, 15302, 15180, 7177, 16193, 8226, 9741, 26237, 12146, 12910, 25820, 29323, 17294, 15219, 26174, 27112, 27131, 28268, 34059, 39162, 38314, 19807, 20606, 21552, 36499, 42163, 30301], 'date': [Timestamp('2014-11-12 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-11-13 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-11-14 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-11-15 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-11-16 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-11-17 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-11-18 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-11-19 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-11-20 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-11-21 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-12-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-12-02 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-12-03 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-12-04 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-12-05 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-12-06 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-12-07 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-12-08 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-12-09 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-12-10 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-12-11 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-12-12 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-12-13 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-12-14 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-12-15 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-12-16 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-12-17 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-12-18 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-12-19 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-12-20 00:00:00')]})
df = df.set_index('date')

grouped = df.groupby(['animal'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for key, group in grouped:
    group['count'].plot(label=key, ax=ax)

plt.legend(loc='best')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to account for additional ordering by month if I've got several months, too? I've tried to add `df['month'] = df.index.month //
df = df.sort('day', 'month')` 

but I got an error that read `No axis named month for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`

Comment: To sort by both `day` and `month` use `df.sort_values(by=['day', 'month'])`. If you use `df.sort('day', 'month')` then the `sort` method thinks `'month'` is the value of the [second argument, which is the `axes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html).

Comment: Hmm... I thought this worked, but I end up with the [following]:(http://imgur.com/fR9FOzC) — still can't get months to appear. I'll edit the question to include another month, sorry about that!

Comment: Do you want to use the date for the `x-axis`? Or do you want the `x-axis` values to be `(month, day)` pairs? (Is there a difference? other than the ticklabels?) What if there are multiple years with the same `(month, day)`? Should the `count` be added together?

Comment: Ah, sorry, here's the clarification: I'd like to keep the date on the `x-axis` — as long as I can see the progression over time, that's perfect. 

I'd like to chart the change in the counts for both animals individually, both across months, and as your thoughtfully pointed out, years. Basically, I'd like the time series to display the counts for each value starting with, say, August 1, 2014 until January 15, 2016.

Comment: or is the only way to do this is split the data frame so that I've got rabbits and dogs as columns, as well as a a column for each of their counts (i.e., rabbit, rabbit_count, dog, dog_count), and then somehow cobble then use raw dates (e.g., 20150101) to plot the progression of each?